# Как правильно клонировать справочник или список

Tags: c#, vb.net

Допустим есть некий справочник такого типа.

```
Dim data As Dictionary(Of String, Tick)
```

Данный справочник заполняется функциями обратного вызова с DDE сервера, программа в которой определен данный справочник является клиентом и не позволяет контролировать процесс заполнения данного справочника.

Далее происходит следующее, данный справочник переодически сбрасывается в базу данных, и при проходе по нему в цике, (если в момент работы с `data`) вносятся изменения, происходит ошибка и останов цикла.

Насколько я понимаю, надо клонировать данный объект но как это правильно сделать не знаю.

Comment: Либо клонировать, если процесс передачи данных весьма продолжителен, либо просто заблокировать объект на момент работы с ним. Но это так, к слову. Eсли я Вас правильно понял, то Ваша проблема заключается в одновременном доступе к объекту из нескольких потоков. В таком случае у Net уже есть встроенное решение: используйте `ConcurrentDictionary`! Почти то же, что и обычный словарь, но он гарантирует полную потокобезопасность для всех операций